# Performance of a Function in a SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i was doing some Tuning Earlier and found some surpising results from my Explain Plans.
I was comparing explain plans between a "Pure SQL Query" and a SQL with a Function.
I was surprised to find that the latter is better in terms of Cost and Access Paths compared to a Pure SQL Query,
especially since i'm under the popular belief that doing it in SQL is faster than Doing it in PL/SQL.

Sample DDL and DML below (ps. just created dummy data and dummy objects for this sample):

```
Create Table EMP_DATA_TL
(
    emp_id          number
  , emp_name        varchar2(100)
  , organization_id number
  , location_id     number
  , Start_date      date
  , end_date        date
);

create table organization_TL
(
    organization_id     number
  , ORGANIZATION_NAME   VARCHAR2(100)
  , Start_date          date
  , end_date            date
);

create table location_TL
(
    location_id     number
  , location_name   varchar2(100)
  , Start_date      date
  , end_date        date
);

insert into EMP_DATA_TL ( emp_id, emp_name, organization_id, location_id, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 1, 'TEST 1', 1, 2, SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into EMP_DATA_TL ( emp_id, emp_name, organization_id, location_id, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 2, 'TEST 2', 1, 3, SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into EMP_DATA_TL ( emp_id, emp_name, organization_id, location_id, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 3, 'TEST 3', 3, 1, SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into organization_TL ( organization_id, ORGANIZATION_NAME, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 1, 'ORG 1', SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into organization_TL ( organization_id, ORGANIZATION_NAME, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 2, 'ORG 2', SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into organization_TL ( organization_id, ORGANIZATION_NAME, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 3, 'ORG 3', SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into location_TL ( location_id, location_name, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 1, 'LOC 1', SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into location_TL ( location_id, location_name, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 2, 'LOC 2', SYSDATE, NULL );
insert into location_TL ( location_id, location_name, Start_date, end_date ) values  ( 3, 'LOC 3', SYSDATE, NULL );

COMMIT;
```

Here is the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE GET_DATA_TST
AS
 FUNCTION GET_ORG (p_organization_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
 FUNCTION GET_LOC (P_LOCATION_ID NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END GET_DATA_TST;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY GET_DATA_TST
AS
 FUNCTION GET_ORG (p_organization_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
 AS
     L_ORG_NAME location_TL.location_name%TYPE; 
 BEGIN     
    SELECT ORGANIZATION_NAME
    INTO   L_ORG_NAME
    FROM   organization_TL
    WHERE  organization_id = p_organization_id;
    return L_ORG_NAME;
 exception 
    when no_data_found then 
        return null; 
 END GET_ORG;

 FUNCTION GET_LOC (P_LOCATION_ID NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
 AS
     L_LOC_NAME location_TL.location_name%TYPE; 
 BEGIN
    SELECT LOCATION_NAME
    INTO   L_LOC_NAME
    FROM   location_TL
    WHERE  location_id = P_LOCATION_ID;
    return L_LOC_NAME;
 exception 
    when no_data_found then 
        return null;    
 END GET_LOC;
END GET_DATA_TST;
```

Gather Table Stats for Accuracy:

```
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('APPS', 'EMP_DATA_TL');
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('APPS', 'organization_TL');
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('APPS', 'location_TL');
```

Query 1: Pure SQL

```
SELECT  EMP.EMP_NAME
    ,   ORG.ORGANIZATION_NAME
    ,   LOC.LOCATION_NAME
FROM    EMP_DATA_TL EMP
    ,   organization_TL ORG
    ,   location_TL LOC
WHERE   EMP.ORGANIZATION_ID = ORG.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND     LOC.LOCATION_ID = EMP.LOCATION_ID
AND     EMP.EMP_NAME = 'TEST 3';
```

Query 1 Results:

```
EMP_NAME    ORGANIZATION_NAME   LOCATION_NAME   
--------    -----------------   -------------
TEST 3      ORG 3               LOC 1
```

Explain Plan of Query 1:

```
Plan hash value: 1708296422

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                 |     1 |    31 |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN          |                 |     1 |    31 |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |                 |     1 |    22 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP_DATA_TL     |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| ORGANIZATION_TL |     3 |    27 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | LOCATION_TL     |     3 |    27 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("LOC"."LOCATION_ID"="EMP"."LOCATION_ID")
   2 - access("EMP"."ORGANIZATION_ID"="ORG"."ORGANIZATION_ID")
   3 - filter("EMP"."EMP_NAME"='TEST 3')
```

Query 2: SQL with Functions

```
SELECT  EMP.EMP_NAME
    ,   GET_DATA_TST.GET_ORG(ORGANIZATION_ID) ORGANIZATION_NAME
    ,   GET_DATA_TST.GET_LOC(LOCATION_ID) LOCATION_NAME
FROM    EMP_DATA_TL EMP
WHERE   EMP.EMP_NAME = 'TEST 3';
```

Query 2 Results (same as Query 1 Results):

```
EMP_NAME    ORGANIZATION_NAME   LOCATION_NAME   
--------    -----------------   -------------
TEST 3      ORG 3               LOC 1
```

Query 2 Explain Plan:

```
Plan hash value: 765802585

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP_DATA_TL |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMP"."EMP_NAME"='TEST 3')
```

Drop Statements just in case you need 'em:

```
DROP TABLE EMP_DATA_TL;
DROP table organization_TL;
DROP table location_TL;
```

Questions:

1. Any Idea why this is the case? or any explanation?
2. Is it recommended to always use Functions for these types of Queries?
3. Please share any other information/tips you might have.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The SQL performed inside the functions is not included in the explain plan. But it doesn't mean that it didn't cost you something. It just wasn't shown to you.

Comment: i thought about that too. Is there a way to know the result of the SQL performed in the Function? and include it in the results? thanks! @sstan

Comment: You could use dbms_profiler to profile pl/sql

Comment: hmm, heard of it, but haven't used that before. any links you can share? :) I'll look it up as well. Thanks! @OldProgrammer

Comment: it is in the oracle docs.  google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Any Idea why this is the case? or any explanation?*  Your test case, while better than 99% of the sample code on Stackoverflow, is still missing a few crucial items.
2. *Is it recommended to always use Functions for these types of Queries?* No.  It is almost always better to avoid functions and use pure SQL.
3. *Please share any other information/tips you might have.* See below for more details.

**What's Missing - Recursive SQL**

As sstan mentioned, the explain plans do not cover recursive SQL statements generated by PL/SQL code.

You can find those recursive SQL statements like these:

```
select sql_id, sql_fulltext from gv$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like 'select organization_name from organization_tl where organization_id = :b1 ';
select sql_id, sql_fulltext from gv$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like 'select location_name from location_tl where location_id%';
```

View the plans with SQL statements like these:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('f25v7jzaru38w'));
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('8akhcs16wn8fd'));
```

Each one has a cost of 3 on my machine.  If you add both of those to the original cost of 5, you get a combined cost of 11.

**What's Missing - Realistic Data and Data Structures**

Comparing a cost of 11 with 15 can be pointless for a few reasons.

When the tables are so small the algorithms to access them almost don't matter.  A table with only a few rows can probably fit inside a single 8KB block.  In that case, a full table scan would always be better than an index read, because an index would require an additional 8KB block.

And how much time difference does this translate into anyway?  One microsecond?  Unless you plan on querying the employee table a billion times the difference doesn't matter.

When the tables get large then the lack of indexes will be crucial.  In that case, those full table scans performed in each function call will be disastrous.  The single query wouldn't be great, but at least it would only have to read from each table once.

**Performance Estimates are Difficult**

Two things to keep in mind whenever you're looking at performance estimates:

1. It is impossible to determine if a program will finish (in general), let alone how long it will take.  This is known as the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).
2. The Oracle optimizer uses many tricks to forecast performance.  But the forecast is always wrong.

This means that difference between 11 and 15 is just noise.  Although it's called the "Cost Based Optimizer", the actual cost isn't that important.  Worry more about the algorithms and data structures you see in the execution plan.  Don't worry about the numbers in the cost or cardinality unless they're off by more than an order of magnitude.

You always have to test with realistic data, realistic data structures, and a realistic environment.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer John! I sure learned from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: 4 years after, i'm re-reading this again and i learned something new again. thanks Jon!

Answer (score -1):

## Functions performance POC

(Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production)

```
create or replace function f return number is begin return 1; end;
/

create table t as 
with t (n) as (select 1 from dual union all select n+1 from t where n < 100)   
select 1 as n from t t0,t t1,t t2,t t3
;
```

---

```
select count(1) from t;
```

**2.5** seconds

```
select count(f()) from t;
```

**58** seconds

Answer (score -2):

give a try with

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
```

to get also the query plan for the routines within the function.

Comment: What's that mean? @DuduMarkovitz

Comment: MySQL syntax, not relevant to Oracle

Comment: ah, yes, i did a quick search on Explain Extended and found it was for MySQL. Thanks.